# Windows 7 32 bit - Backing up my settings then installing W7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a LOT of settings from installed programs on my current Windows 7 Ultimate RC (32 bit) installation, but I've made a point of putting all of my files (work, downloads, documents, etc) somewhere within my User folder as Windows seems to prefer.

Is it safe to run the facility that lets you backup your files and settings, then come back, install Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit (full), then once I've installed my programs, restore files and settings? Is this the correct order to do this? Can I even do it when switching between 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Windows Easy Trasnfer seems to work very well and people like it - it transfers over all settings and documents and then allows you to reinstall all your programs easily.

That being said, as a long term geek, I am not ready to use such a tool, but I know everyone who has, has ended up liking it and working fine.

Comment: It worked for me on Vista. I seemed to remember the Outlook .pst needed special attention.